# MySQL Merge rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have done some research but still couldnt solve my issue here.

I have this table in next image link: 
[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En5aV.png)

Im trying to write a query so that I can get something like this image link:
[Sample I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gce9M.png)

I did try write a query as below :

`select ticket_pic, case when status = 'open' then count(tickets_id) end as open_ticket, case when status = 'close' then count(tickets_id) end as close_ticket  from gt_tickets group by ticket_pic, status`

But it return wrong data
Please advice. Any hint will be much appreciate.

Cheers

Comment: Reading your question in the Triage Review for me it's completely unclear what you mean by "I can get something like this image link".

Comment: @Matthias. My apologize if its unclear. actually "I can get something like this image link" refer to the link next to it. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ticket_pic,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as open_ticket,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'close' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as close_ticket      
from gt_tickets
group by ticket_pic
```

OR

```
select ticket_pic,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'open' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as open_ticket,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'close' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as   close_ticket        
from gt_tickets
group by ticket_pic
```

Answer (score 1):

I might as well point out that the simplest syntax in MySQL is:

```
select ticket_pic,
       sum(status = 'open') as open_ticket,
       sum(status = 'close') as close_ticket 
from gt_tickets
group by ticket_pic;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers, in a numeric context, with "0" for false and "1" for true.